# Toggling classes or visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, hide, show

I'm using this code for toggling visibility of a class, but once hidden, elements are not becoming visible again. Look at my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gutierrez100/gM35F/2/). Click on "1", and then click on "All" for hidinh and showing all items.

```
var toggle_visibility = (function() {
    function toggle(cl) {
        var els = document.getElementsByClassName(cl);
        for(var i=0; i<els.length; ++i) {
            var s = els[i].style;
            s.display = s.display==='none' ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
        };
    }
    return function(cl) {
        if (cl instanceof Array) {
            for(var i=0; i<cl.length; ++i) {
                toggle(cl[i]);
            }
        }
        else {
            toggle(cl);
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What do you expect your Fiddle to do that it's currently not doing?

Comment: And a big **+1** for providing a fiddle with your first question.

Comment: Hi, I update the code, see: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gutierrez100/gM35F/9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `item-all` is a container of `item-01`, `item-02` and `item-03`. If you want to show, let's say, `item-01` when `item-all` is hidden, you'll have to make it visible again.

An option according your code and HTML would be using

```
toggle_visibility('iconMap-3');
```

instead of

```
toggle_visibility('item-all');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gM35F/6/)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code and playing with the fiddle, it's pretty obvious what is going on.  the Show/Hide all button is changing the ul class to display or not, which affects all the li tags.  if you set the none at the ul it turns off the whole list, if you click on 1,2 or 3 the list items get display turned on and off individually.  Click 1, click all, click 3, click all.  see what's happening? you are using visibility at different levels.

Click 1

```
<ul class="item-all">
    <li class="iconMap-3 item-01" style="display:none;"/>1
    <li class="iconMap-3 item-02"/>2
    <li class="iconMap-3 item-03"/>3
</ul>
```

Click All

```
 <ul class="item-all" style="display:none;">
    <li class="iconMap-3 item-01" style="display:none;"/>1
    <li class="iconMap-3 item-02"/>2
    <li class="iconMap-3 item-03"/>3
</ul>
```

Click 3

```
<ul class="item-all" style="display:none;">
    <li class="iconMap-3 item-01" style="display:none;"/>1
    <li class="iconMap-3 item-02"/>2
    <li class="iconMap-3 item-03"  style="display:none;"/>3
</ul>
```

Click all

```
<ul class="item-all">
    <li class="iconMap-3 item-01" style="display:none;"/>1
    <li class="iconMap-3 item-02"/>2
    <li class="iconMap-3 item-03"  style="display:none;"/>3
</ul>
```